# Stop huge error output from testing-library

Tags: react-testing-library, angular-testing-library

I love `testing-library`, have used it a lot in a React project, and I'm trying to use it in an Angular project now - but I've always struggled with the enormous error output, including the HTML text of the render. Not only is this not usually helpful (I couldn't find an element, here's the HTML where it *isn't*); but it gets truncated, often before the interesting line if you're running in debug mode.

I simply added it as a library alongside the standard Angular Karma+Jasmine setup.

I'm sure you could say the components I'm testing are too large if the HTML output causes my console window to spool for ages, but I have a lot of integration tests in Protractor, and they are *SO SLOW* :(.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I would say the best solution would be to use the `configure` method and pass a custom function for `getElementError` which does what you want.

You can read about configuration here: https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-configuration

An example of this might look like:

```js
configure({
  getElementError: (message: string, container) => {
    const error = new Error(message);
    error.name = 'TestingLibraryElementError';
    error.stack = null;
    return error;
  },
});
```

You can then put this in any single test file or use Jest's [setupFiles](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#setupfiles-array) or [setupFilesAfterEnv](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#setupfilesafterenv-array) config options to have it run globally.

Comment: My example above is TypeScript, BTW - you might not want `: string` if you're using Jest with React in a non-TS project!

Comment: After a recent update to webpack (`5.61.0`), this seems to not be working anymore. Can anyone else confirm that this is still working (with or even without webpack in the equation)?

Comment: Set the configuration in `setupFiles` would be break the feature of [cleanup automatically](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/api/#cleanup), so it is better to set the config in `setupFilesAfterEnv`. Please see [Cleanup not happening when using configure from @testing-library/react](https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library/issues/666)

Answer (score 14):

I am assuming you running jest with rtl in your project.

I personally wouldn't turn it off as it's there to help us, but everyone has a way so if you have your reasons, then fair enough.

**1. If you want to disable errors for a specific test, you can mock the `console.error`.**

```
    it('disable error example', () => {

  const errorObject = console.error; //store the state of the object
  console.error = jest.fn(); // mock the object

  // code

  //assertion (expect)

  console.error = errorObject; // assign it back so you can use it in the next test
});
```

**2. If you want to silence it for all the test, you could use the `jest --silent` CLI option. Check the [docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/cli#--silent)**

The above might even disable the DOM printing that is done by rtl, I am not sure as I haven't tried this, but if you look at the docs I linked, it says

> "Prevent tests from printing messages through the console."

Now you almost certainly have everything disabled except the DOM recommendations if the above doesn't work. On that case you might look into `react-testing-library's` source code and find out what is used for those print statements. Is it a `console.log`? is it a `console.warn`? When you got that, just mock it out like **option 1 above.**

**UPDATE**

After some digging, I found out that all `testing-library` DOM printing is built on `prettyDOM()`;

While `prettyDOM()` can't be disabled you can limit the number of lines to 0, and that would just give you the error message and three dots `...` below the message.

Here is an example printout, I messed around with:

```
    TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element with the text: Hello ther. This could be because the text is broken up by multiple elements. In this case, you can provide a function for your text matcher to make your matcher more flexible.

...
```

All you need to do is to pass in an environment variable before executing your test suite, so for example with an npm script it would look like:

```
DEBUG_PRINT_LIMIT=0 npm run test
```

[Here is the doc](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-helpers#debugging)

**UPDATE 2**:

As per the OP's [FR on github](https://github.com/testing-library/dom-testing-library/issues/773) this can also be achieved without injecting in a global variable to limit the PrettyDOM line output (in case if it's used elsewhere). The `getElementError` config option need to be changed:

**dom-testing-library/src/config.js**

```
     // called when getBy* queries fail. (message, container) => Error 
 getElementError(message, container) { 
   const error = new Error( 
     [message, prettyDOM(container)].filter(Boolean).join('\n\n'), 
   ) 
   error.name = 'TestingLibraryElementError' 
   return error 
 },
```

[The callstack can also be removed](https://github.com/testing-library/dom-testing-library/issues/773#issuecomment-700684282)

Comment: Oh no! Thank you so much for your reply and I'm _SO_ sorry I forgot to say I'm not using jest! I'm just using Karma (with jasmine, as per normal for Angular). SORRY! :(

Comment: Ah I see, sorry I am not that literate with the Angular ecosystem. Regardless of the testing framework `console.error` `console.warn` etc is the same everywhere. Wouldn't it work by mocking it out with the tools you have?

Comment: removing console would make life very difficult. I want to stop it spooling a load of HTML onto the commandline pointlessley when there's a failure.

Comment: @IanGrainger I updated my answer, I might have a solution for you. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks - though I normally use prettyDOM for my own debugging :(

Comment: I tried this after reading: https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-helpers 'Note: Since the DOM can get very large'.... Why is that OK!?  and it didn't work, because I'm running via Karma I guess 

Comment: I never used Karma but it's a test runner. PrettyDOM is not part of Jest, so theoretically it should be used with any kind of Test runner and package manager(s). At this point, maybe it's worth raising a feature request on testing-library's github to be able to limit the length of the DOM on a test by test basis?

Comment: the problem is that Karma ignores env vars set on the commandline, because it runs Chrome (which runs the test) in an other process. The first place that testing library point you is here, to SO - so that's why this is here first!

Comment: I *think* this is done by the DOM testing library, so I've created a FR here: https://github.com/testing-library/dom-testing-library/issues/773

Comment: Yepp, that's correct  - react testing library as an abstraction of the dom testing library is inheriting the feature, I noticed when I was looking into PrettyDOM. I also see you received an answer, that's great. I would complete wyze's answer by: the `config.js` code snippet states: `// called when getBy* queries fail. (message, container) => Error` - this won't cover the `queryBy` queries, so you need to cover that as well, I believe.

Comment: Oops, didn't see you'd updated. I'd added a copy of wyze's answer here. But seeing as I presumably don't get points for my own answer - I may as well take yours! :)

Comment: Sorry, bro. The guy that answered on GH has come over here - so I've moved the points. Thanks for your help, too! 

Answer (score 2):

You can change how the message is built by setting the DOM testing library message building function with config. In my Angular project I added this to `test.js`:

```
configure({
  getElementError: (message: string, container) => {
    const error = new Error(message);
    error.name = 'TestingLibraryElementError';
    error.stack = null;
    return error;
  },
});
```

This was answered here: https://github.com/testing-library/dom-testing-library/issues/773 by https://github.com/wyze.